# How could I change file creation/modification date from filename?

Tags: windows-10, filenames, date, extract

I have a bunch of pictures that each have its creation date in the filename with this format: IMG-YYYYMMDD-WAXXXX.jpg
but when moved from smartphone internal memory to sd card, all the pictures got its creation & modification date altered and now they won't display in correct order.

What I need is to take the date from the filename to then modify the file creation date to this. I'm on Win10.

Comment: I am neither psychic nor a mind reader and I don't like guessing games.  What is your operating system? Please [edit] the question and include this essential information.

Answer (score 6):

[Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/method_timestamp) can change the file date attributes based on a pattern in the filename.

[image]